# Bone rotation not working in pose mode

Tags: rigging, bones, pose-mode, bone.constraints

I'm using Blender 3.4 and am having trouble with my rig. I used a basic human meta rig for my character and then made a rig for my hands.

I added some constraints to the bones and it was working perfectly,but then I don't know what I did,all of a sudden my leg bones don't rotate in pose mode, specifically the thigh bones, all the other bones rotate except them.

Here is a picture with the constraints that I put on the bone, but really it was working just fine and I'm not sure if that is the problem.

[image]

The constraints were just to make my characters legs rotate in a more natural way.

Comment: Hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/